# Initial unprecise float value

Tags: swift

Can someone explain this behaviour to me? Why is the float value initially not as precise as I would expect? Why is the double cast creating an even less precise value?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for educating me. Just one problem: I receive the double value 0.99 from an API which I decode. Is there any way I don't end up with this rounding error?